# Keep quotes when creating data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` containing many columns. From these, I extract two (`col1` and `col2`) and use `df2 = data.frame(df$col1, df$col2)` for this.

It works: a new dataframe made of those two columns is created. But `df$col1` was made of strings as:

```
"test1"
"test2"
```

`df2$col1` is made instead of values (not sure how to call them) as:

```
test1
test2
```

Intersection between these `df$col1` and `df2$col1` yields zero. How do I keep the column as a string in the new data frame?

I tried adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you try `df2$col1 <- as.character(df2$col1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'df' is your data frame and you do not want to change the original data type. i.e., you should retain your string data type.

So basically you should subset those columns from the original data frame instead of creating a new data frame using 'data.frame'.

```
> df2<-df[,c("col1","col2")]
```

You can check the data type of each column in data frame by

```
> str(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first data.frame has `col1` set as character. When you create a second data.frame, this character column is coerced to factor. Here's a possible short proof.

```
> df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b", "c"), col2 = 1:3)
> df1$col1
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
> df1$col1 <- as.character(df1$col1)
> df1$col1
[1] "a" "b" "c" # this is what you have
> 
> df2 <- data.frame(col1 = df1$col1)
> df2$col1
[1] a b c # coerced to factor
Levels: a b c
```

Comment: It works, but the other is cleaner so I accepted that. Thanks anyway!